# Disjoint union of $\Lambda^k(T_p U)$ as a bundle.

Tags: differential-geometry, smooth-manifolds, differential-forms, vector-fields, tangent-spaces

While studying differential geometry of Manifolds,one has surely come across the space of all alternating $k$-tensors on a vector space $V$ (say of finite dimension $n$). We denote it by
$$
\Lambda^k(V) := \{T\in {V^{\otimes^k}}: T\text{ is an alternating tensor} \}
$$
which has a canonical basis $\{e_{i_1}\wedge e_{i_2}\wedge\cdots\wedge e_{i_k}: 1\leq i_1<i_2<\cdots<i_k\leq n\}$. Now suppose $U$ is an open set in $\mathbb R^n$. Now, a **differential $k$ form** on $U$ is defined to be a map
$$
\omega: U \to \bigcup_{p\in U} \Lambda^k(T_pU)
$$
such that the following are satisfied:

$(1)\quad \omega(p)\in \Lambda^k(T_pU)$,

$(2)\quad$ The functions $c_{i_1,\ldots,i_k}: U\to \mathbb R$ are $C^\infty$ smooth for all $1\leq i_1<\cdots<i_k\leq n$,
where
$$
\omega(p) = \sum_{1\leq i_1<\cdots<i_k\leq n} 
c_{i_1,i_2,\ldots,i_k}(p) \, 
dx_{i_1}|_p \wedge \cdots \wedge dx_{i_k}|_p
$$
is the unique basis representation of $\omega(p)$ in terms of the canonical basis.

I want to know if there is a specific standard name for the disjoint union $\bigcup_{p\in U}\Lambda^k(T_pU)$ similar to what we have in case of vector fields where we call $TM=\bigcup_{p\in M} T_p(M)$, which is the disjoint union of the tangent spaces, by the name **Tangent Bundle** and we can think of a vector field as a section of the tangent bundle.

I am curious to know whether we have anything similar for the alternating tensors and whether we can look at the differential forms as a section of the bundle.

**Note**

I am not familiar with bundles and know very little about them. So, I need some help to get my question answered. Is there anyone who can provide me with a satisfactory one and at the same time give me some insight about what the bundle means for alternating tensors?

Comment: *“$k^{th}$ exterior power of $TM$”*, (or maybe you want to specialize to $U$ for whatever reason) thats what its called. In general for “any” vector space operation (direct sum, tensor product, exterior power, Hom spaces) there is a corresponding notion at the vector bundle level. For the terminology and notation see [Clarification on notation regarding fields, forms, and exterior algebra](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/4221303/568204). For showing that the results are actually vector bundles, you really just need to unwind definitions or just refer to a standard textbook.